# Missing arguments to Python function - error detection in IDE

Tags: python, ide

I've been setting up a couple of IDE for Python. I'm surprised that IDE (used e.g. Spyder or VS Code) do not highlight error if an argument is missing. Is this is not expected?

```
def say(what):
    print(what)

say()  # no error?
```

Comment: I get an error on PyCharm

Comment: @rak007 Are you sure it's an error? For me it's just a warning. That's why I'm also here for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the "static code analysis" tool in Spyder (toolbar -> source -> Run Static Code Analysis (F8)). There is no live static checking.

PyCharm has this functionality though and will warn about errors like this in the editor.

[image]

I don't have VScode so can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

I get error in Vscode with your code.
The extension I use is [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).
[image]